# 'Collapse' is not defined react/jsx-no-undef

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, sidebar

I am new in React, Now I am trying to do sidebar and hide show collapse menu item.

here is function=>

```
 collapsemetoggle(){
        this.setState(state => ({ collapsemeopen: !state.collapsemeopen }));
      }


 <div className="list-group list-group-flush">
          <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>              
          <a onClick={this.collapsemetoggle} data-toggle="collapse" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Collapase Me</a>

          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.collapsemeopen}>
            <div className="list-group list-group-flush">
              <a href="#" className="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">Dashboard</a>                  
            </div>
          </Collapse>
        </div>

      </div>
```

But why

> 'Collapse' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef

is shown? I just reference from here=>

[React Transition](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/utilities/transitions/)

I am trying to achieve to get sidebar like =>

[Sidebar](https://coreui.io/react/demo/#/dashboard)

Other people use `ul li` for menu list and I am trying to do with `collapse`. Is it the correct way? If not, Plase let me know for some example.

Comment: can you add what your imports are at the top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import Collapse:

```
import {Collapse} from 'react-bootstrap'
```

use props in  instead of isOpen

```
 <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
      <div id="example-collapse-text">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus
        terry richardson ad squid. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer
        labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
      </div>
    </Collapse>
```

Answer (score 1):

When using Bootstrap or any other UI framework, you need to import the component you're using. Put this on top of your file and it will automatically import it.

```
import Collapse from 'react-bootstrap/Collapse'
```

By the way, the `isOpen` prop is not a Collapse prop. You should use `in`

```
<Collapse in={this.state.collapsemeopen}>
```

Comment: after adding this, React does not recognize the `isOpen` prop on a DOM element is shown.

Comment: @Jze because ``<Collapse/>`` does NOT have an isOpen prop. Replace it by the ``in`` prop.

Comment: By what you are trying to achieve you need to use `in` prop instead of `isOpen`